# I had Boost protein shakes in my refrigerator and it went out. The refrigerator is fixed, can I refrigerate them again and use?

Tags: food-safety

The shakes are purchased dry and i store extras in my pantry. I'm just not sure since they went from cold to room temp if I can still use them and put the unused ones back in the refrigerator.

Comment: As they’re sold in packaging that’s shelf stable, so long as the package hasn’t been opened (thus exposed to air (oxygen) and whatever microbes might be in it), they should be fine.

Comment: (And because they’re not temperature sensitive, the question that was marked as a duplicate doesn’t apply in this situation)

Comment: It's not clear whether they were still dry or rehydrated when they went in the fridge.

Comment: @Tetsujin the stores around me sell it as a liquid for ‘shakes’ and the dry stuff is sold as ‘powder’, so I assumed it was the bottles of liquid